# Magento 2.3 get attribute id from attribute Label

Tags: magento2.3, eav-attributes, labels

I want to get product **attribute id** from **attribute Label**

> example: attribute label = Manufacturer

I want to get **Manufacture attribute id** from **attribute Label**

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have attribute code or just label only?

Comment: i want to attribute code or attribute id by attribute label

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this below code to get **attribute_id** & **attribute_code** by using **attribute label** :

**Construct Method :**

```
protected $eavAttribute;

public function __construct(
    ....
    \Magento\Eav\Model\Attribute $eavAttribute,
    ....
){
    ....
    $this->eavAttribute = $eavAttribute;
    ....
}

public function yourFunction()
{
    $label = 'Manufacture';
    $attributeCollection = $this->eavAttribute->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('frontend_label', ['eq' => $label])->getLastItem();
    echo $attributeCollection->getAttributeId(); // attribute ID
    echo $attributeCollection->getAttributeCode(); // attribute Code
}
```

**Object Manager Method :**

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$eavAttrObj = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Eav\Model\Attribute')->getCollection();
$attributeCollection = $eavAttrObj->addFieldToFilter('frontend_label', ['eq' => 'Created From'])->getLastItem();
echo $attributeCollection->getAttributeId();
echo $attributeCollection->getAttributeCode();
```

Use **getLastItem()** only if you have just a single record of that item. You can use **backend_label** instead of **frontend_label** if you want to perform in the backend side.

> Note: I always recommended to use a construct method and avoid object manager.

**Hope, It will helpful for you.**